# Getting the textbox value into the jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Can i get the textbox value into the jquery using its name property and not by the Id property.
For example

```
<input type = "text" name="text-box" value='1'/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course. Try it:

```
$('input[name="text-box"]').val();
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this code. But it is not working for me. Can you please help me </br>    $(document).ready(function () {
   
  $('input[name="text-box"]').keypress(function (e) {
     
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
       
        $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
               return false;
    }
   });
});

Comment: You are showing the error and then hide it. All looks ok.